# Magento Enterprise product, category to website relationship

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, catalogsearch

In Magento Enterprise what table and column names store the relationship of product id -> category id -> website id

So if I have a multi-website Magento install and what I want to do is run a mysql query (using PHP language) that would pull all products (product name, price and unique ID where the product name is 'LIKE' xyz and the magento website currently being viewed by the user is a and the current store view being viewed by the user is b. What might my query look like.

Basically I am looking to alter the Magento product search to only search/display products that are assigned/enabled in the website and store view the user is currently browsing.

I know how to get the unique ID of the website and store view the user is currently browsing already.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The category to product relation is stored in `catalog_category_product` table.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also know what table stores to product to website relationship? Or category to website relationship?

Answer (score 2):

As answer to:

> Do you also know what table stores to product to website relationship? Or category to website relationship?

The table `catalog_product_website` contains the product to website relationship (no surprise, isn't it?)

The **category tree** is assigned to each **store group** of the website using the field `root_category_id` in `core_store_group`. So the relationship between each category and a website is indirect:

```
website
 + store group
    + root category
       + category
          + subcategory
 + store group
   ...
```